# Comparacion basica - Input y Objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito hacer una comparación(if) entre el **valor** de un input con 2 propiedades de un objeto y si coinciden, que entre al sistema.

```
function datosPersonal(usuario, correo, dni, contraseña) {
    //Objeto Personal
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
  }

    var lauty = new datosPersonal('lauty', 'ssss@hotmail.com.ar', '23232323', '123321');
    var danielitax = new datosPersonal('danielitax', 'daniela_20@gmail.com', '41111111', 'daniela123');


$('#goLogin').click(function(){
    var user = $('#inputUser').val();
    var pass = $('#inputPassword').val();
});
```

Hice el un if como este:

```
$('#goLogin').click(function(){
    var user = $('#inputUser').val();
    var pass = $('#inputPassword').val();

    if(user == user.usuario && pass == user.contraseña) {
        alert('Logeado');
    } else {
        alert('Los datos no coinciden.')
    }
});
```

> En el if, al poner **user.usuario** **user.contraseña** la variable user, quiero que me la tome, por el valor ingresado en el input. Ese es mi problema!

Comment: ¿`user.usuario` y `user.contraseña` ya los tienes registrados en una instancia del objeto?

Comment: user vendria a ser la variable del valor del input Usuario y .usuario .password las propiedades del objeto.

Necesito que user sea reemplazado por el valor del input que se ingrese en el login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahi logre hacerlo con **Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor**

> Asi quedo:

```
var userLocal = $("[name='inputUser']").val();
    var pass = $("[name='inputPassword']").val();
    var datoUsuario = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window[userLocal] , 'usuario').value;
    var datoContraseña = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window[userLocal], 'contraseña').value;

    if(userLocal == datoUsuario && pass == datoContraseña) {
        alert('Logeado');
    } else {
        alert('Los datos no coinciden.')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que renombrar la variable `user` a otro nombre porque siempre se le dará mas prioridad a los objetos locales que tengan el mismo nombre que un objeto de ambito mas global.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var usuario = { nombre: "einer" };

function imprimirNombreUsuario(parametro)
{
  var usuario = parametro.toUpperCase();
  console.log(usuario);
  
}

imprimirNombreUsuario("matias");
```

La variable local `usuario` tiene un ambito mas cercano que la variable global `usuario` por lo que si queremos acceder al objeto con el ambito mas lejano, tenemos que renombrar la variable local y listo:

```js
var usuario = { nombre: "einer" };

function imprimirNombreUsuario(parametro)
{
  var usuario_local = parametro.toUpperCase();
  console.log(usuario_local);
  console.log(usuario.nombre);
}

imprimirNombreUsuario("matias");
```

En tu caso seria simplemente renombrar la variable local `user` a cualquier otro nombre:

```
$('#goLogin').click(function(){
    var userLocal = $('#inputUser').val();
    var pass = $('#inputPassword').val();

    if(userLocal == user.usuario && pass == user.contraseña) {
        alert('Logeado');
    } else {
        alert('Los datos no coinciden.')
    }
});
```

Comment: Pero la variable user al ponerla asi : user.usuario me tira undefined por que no toma el user como una variable, sino como un objeto, lo que quiero es que me tome el user como el valor de $('#inputUser').val();

Cuando el if hace la comparacion de igualdad compara el valor del input con la propiedad 'usuario' y 'password' del objeto user, pero al no existir ese objeto tira 'undefined'

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor, esto es lo que quiero lograr: 

`if(($('#inputUser').val()) == ($('#inputUser').val().usuario) && ($('#inputPassword').val()) == ($('#inputPassword').val().contraseña)) {
        alert('Logeado');
    } else {
        alert('Los datos no coinciden.')
    }`

Comment: la funcion `val()` returna `String` por lo que nunca tendra una propiedad usuario. Con `.val()` solo podras obtener el texto del input.